# EnumChildWindows gives all elements of a window(Java). But how to know which button is clicked by user?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

the code below gives me all elements of any window but i want to know the particular button/link/textbox accessed by user ...

```
User32.INSTANCE.EnumChildWindows(GetForegroundWindow(),
                    new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {
                        int count = 1;

                        public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer userData) {
                            byte[] textBuffer = new byte[512];
                            User32.INSTANCE.GetClassNameA(hWnd, textBuffer, 512);
                                    byte[] childBuffer = new byte[512];
                            User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, childBuffer, 512);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }, null);
```

Comment: Typically, JAVA controls are not windowed, so EnumChildwindows is useless. Could you please elaborate a little more on the context? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually, i'm trying to create an app which can **trace** all user **actions**, in java. Till now i can get all information like: which is the active window, what is the class of window,caption of window, which are components of that active window and also the captions and classes of those components. But i don't want all components of the active window i just want to get **information(class,caption,etc)** of only that **element** which is **clicked by user**.

Comment: As I said, java components are typically NOT windowed. You CAN'T use Win32 for that.

Comment: I want to clarify more.. Let me give you an example:                  If I open the calculator, and click as 1+2=3, our application(which is written in java) should tell us like:                                     class : Button caption : 1                                        class : Button caption : +                                        class : Button caption : 2 and so on.. If I open MS-Office in that also, application should capture all actions performed by user..

Comment: Till now the app tells me that Calculator is opened and what is the title and what is the processId. It also tells that there are 28 components having **Button** class. But I m not able to trace out what user is doing on calculator and which button is being clicked by user.

Comment: Much clearer. You want to code a "super-spy" in Java. You may have to use the Win32 hook API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589.aspx and/or the UI Automation API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx

Comment: I think **SysMsgProc** is the function with the help of which I can get the button, but I m not sure, and also don't know how to call it.

Comment: Coding a "super-spy" is complex, especially if you target arbitrary applications. Doing it JAVA is harder. May I ask what kind of application you want to spy on? and why do you want to use JAVA for that?

Comment: I just want to spy on everything that is happening on the system. There is no specific reason for java and I m almost completed the app. Only the last step is remaining, I want to hook all those button events, but failing to achieve it.

Comment: If the "buttons" are html buttons (in Web Pages) or other *Non Windowed* "buttons" as may exist in various other application types, then SysMsgProc will be useless. I suggest you dive in UIAutomation.

Comment: Can u suggest me another language t do this. I need help in coding.

Comment: If I were to code a super-spy, I would do it in C++. Others would choose C#. To much comments here. Ask precise questions when you have precise problems.